# Integrating $\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{x}}$ .

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I integrate the following algebraic function?

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{x}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate by parts to get

$$x\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{x}} - \frac{1}{2}\int \left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-1/2}\frac{1}{x} \; dx.$$

The last integral can me made into

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x^2-ax}} \; dx,$$

so complete the square and substitute $u=x-a/2$ to get

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{u^2-a^2/4}} \; du$$

which, by standard techniques becomes

$$\sqrt{a}\ln ( 2 u +\sqrt{4u^2-a^2}).$$

Then plug everything in.  And may God have mercy on your soul.

Comment: @B.Goddard...How does 1/2 pop out...?

Comment: The derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ has a $1/2$ in it.

Comment: Very nice observation on doing parts.

Comment: @B.Goddard ... Which expression should I select as "v"  and "du"...?

Comment: Use $du = dx$, eh?

Comment: @B.Goddard... Can I  use ∫v du=uv -∫u dv ... with v=the square rooted equation...?

Comment: That's what I did.

Answer (score 2):

substituting $$t=\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{x}}$$ then we get $$x=\frac{a}{1-at^2}$$ and 
$$dx=\frac{2at}{(1-at^2)^{2}}dt$$
this is a better way!and so we get
$$\int\frac{2a^2t^2}{(1-at^2)^2}dt$$
Can you solve this?
we have $$x=a(1-at^2)^{-1}$$ then $$dx=a(-1)(1-at^2)^{-2}(-2at)dt$$
is it clear now?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ... What next? There appears a √t ...

Comment: so i have added some lines, this is a better way!

Comment: we get $$t^2-\frac{1}{a}=-\frac{1}{x}$$ from squaring the square root

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner...It would be 2a²t²...

Comment: what is your question now?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ...Got it.Thank you...

Comment: i wish you a nice day, sorry for my mistake!

Comment: Or in end perform partial fraction. Don't worry all make mistakes, and liked the answer. Regards.